# How to add a Javascript onclick event in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, mailchimp

So I'm trying to add a Javascript event from Mailchimp that will trigger a Mailchimp workflow if someone clicks 'Help', that will send them a follow-up e-mail asking if they received a response and whether or not it was helpful to them. The snippet offered by MC is as follows,

```
<a href="#" onclick="$mcGoal.processEvent('HelpTestEvent');">HTEvent</a>
```

So far, I've tried directly putting it into our own .php file that loads the navbar just for testing.  What I tried was,

```
$items .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" onclick="$mcGoal.processEvent('HelpTestEvent');">HTEvent</a></li>';
```

except the server errors out.

What would be best practice (or what would you do) if you wanted to trigger this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes:

```
$items .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" onclick="$mcGoal.processEvent(\'HelpTestEvent\');">HTEvent</a></li>';
```

Comment: Great I'm no longer erroring out!  Time to get the MC aspect working.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider clicking the check mark next to this answer, to select it as "correct".

Comment: There we go!  I've got tracking working now.  Thanks so much.